# PHP: Change the input type data based on the form in Edit profile

Tags: php

I have an edit form in PHP where it populates the fields based on the user:

```
$pphone = $get_user_details_arr[0]->pphone;
<input type="text" maxlength="14" class="form-control <?php echo ((array_key_exists('pphone', $error)) ? $err_valid : '');?>" name="pphone" value="<?=$pphone?>" />
```

But when a user edits his/her profile, and makes a validation error, the field is highlighted but the value here is refreshed to the original one, not the one that the user entered.

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user edits a field and if makes a validation error, the value should be the cuurent one. Please suggest a way to achieve it in PHP.

**EDIT**

```
 <select name="enroll_status">
<?php $get_enroll_status = $wpdb->get_results("select enroll_status_id,enroll_status_name from  enroll_status where 1 order by enroll_status_id");
foreach($get_enroll_status as $e_status) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $e_status->enroll_status_id;?>" <?php echo ($get_cust_details[0]->status==$e_status->enroll_status_id) ? 'selected="selected"': "";?>><?php echo $e_status->enroll_status_name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: In case your validation is in PHP (and not js) you can overwrite the `$pphone` value. Let me know if this is the case and i'll write a full answer

Comment: @OfirBaruch, yes my validations are in PHP. But right now I'm stuck for Select tags. Can you suggest a way to go for it!

Comment: Check out @panther comment regarding the `Select` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Put there condition if `$_POST/$_GET` data exists.

```
<input [...] value="<?php echo isset($_POST['pphone']) ? $_POST['pphone'] : $pphone ?>">
```

Comment: One more thing @panther, how do I do it for Select values?

Comment: @CodeKaro: each option will have st. like `echo isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] == 'this val' || $name == 'this val' ? ' selected' : ''`.